# Опять немедленно

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Кажется, вместо "немедленно" нужен какой-то другой перевод для нулевого времени.

[image: скриншот боковой панели]

[image: скриншот палели]

Comment: Сейчас/прямо сейчас?

Comment: только что? . .

Comment: @dIm0n, думаю, да.

Comment: @andreymal, нет. Если бы уже закончились, на втором скриншоте было бы "закончились" (как сейчас), а там "заканчиваются", значит "только что" не подходит.

Comment: @Qwertiy если время нулевое, значит уже закончились и значит нужно исправлять фразу целиком)

Comment: @andreymal, нет, сейчас страницу открой, или мой соседний вопрос - там фраза другая. И там ещё строчка про скачивание результатов. Значит, когда вывелось "немедленно", выборы ещё не закончились.

Comment: Значит нужно писать «через N секунд/минут» без всяких этих костылей)

Comment: И если время на самом деле ненулевое, значит текст вопроса врёт

Comment: @andreymal, скорее всего голосование не заканчивается пока оставшееся время >= 0. Думаю, там было ровно 0 - я специально страницу обновлял в последние ссекунды.

Comment: Кстати, с конкурсами такая же фигня. А ещё есть баг с "1 минута". Например, загружаешь страницу, а там написано: "До конца осталось 30 минут.". Обновляешь страницу и теперь там: "До конца осталось 1 минута.". Ещё раз обновляешь и уже 29 минут например.